# Using undefined CSS media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I was researching about CSS media queries best practices and found the [Foundation's definition](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/media-queries.html).

As you can see, the first media query has no min/max-size definition:

> @media only screen { } /* Define mobile styles */

Why do they use this media query as it defines no break-point? Is this a best practice or should be avoided?

Thanks!

Comment: It targets only `screen`'s (displays) rather than other medias such as `print`. Width and height aren't the only things media queries are used for.

Comment: Why would it need breakpoints? That's just saying screen as opposed to e.g. print. In those examples they are doing *mobile first*, so the breakpoints are then shown for *larger* screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! Yeah, you're right. I was just wondering if, when developing responsive websites, general CSS (i.e. rules used for every screen sizes) should be outside media queries or inside a media query like this one used by Foundation - a media query without screen-size specs. Maybe it's just matter of organization/preference in this case then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular media query applies to all `screen`s (of any size, orientation, aspect ratio or pixel density).
`screen` is a media type. Whatever you put inside that media query will only apply to `screen` and will not apply to content of other `media_type`s.

Here is the [list of currently recognized values](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#media-types) for `media_type`. Most of them have been deprecated. The ones you should use (as they are probably here to stay) are:

- `all` (implicit if none specified)
- `screen`
- `print`
- `speech`

---

The guys at Foundation probably should change the comment after that query to a more explicit one. Instead of `/* Define mobile styles */` they should have probably used `/* General styles, including mobile */`.

Look at the structure of their media queries and you will notice it is a *mobile-first CSS framework*. As in: you define the general styles (including mobile) first and than apply exceptions for ever increasingly wider screens.

Answer (score 2):

Media queries are not only for breakpoints. You can specify the output medium like `screen`. In this case, only display screens are targeted. You can also target only `print` media, or media with specific orientation or resolution.

See more information about media queries and media types on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) or [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).